# regex with php for string replacement not working properly

Tags: php, regex

I was trying to understand the logic behind the regular expression in a preg_replace action in php, but I don't get it.

I am trying to intercept a string like `width="560"` and replace it with `width="100%"`.

The integer value is naturally not constant, so i cannot use a simple str_replace call.

I tried with `preg_replace("/(\d)/", "100%", $input_lines);` where `$input_lines = 'width="560"';`

but I get: `width="100%100%100%"`

I am missing something about recursiveness.
Any clue?

EDIT
After the community answers, I have to add some specs to my post.

What I am trying to do is taking a youtube embed code like

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_qvp9a1x2UM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and replace 560 with 100% and 315 with a calculated value

Comment: No recursive behavior is observed here. Your pattern matches each digit sequentially, and each is replaced with your replacement string. One hint: there is no need to use capturing group if you are not using any backreferences, and if it is set to the whole pattern (unless you are splitting with `preg_split`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `(\d+)`.`+` searches for the pattern one or more times.

```
preg_replace("/(\d+)/", "100%", $input_lines);
```

As per your update your regex should be:

```
preg_replace("width=\"(\d+)\" height=\"(\d+)\"", "width=\"100%\" height=\"your calculated value\"", $input_lines);
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jB1zI1/3)

Comment: thanks, it works fine! What if i wanted to replace the "width" word too? Say with "height".

Comment: if you want to change only `width` substitute this `(\w+)` with `height`. And if you want to change both substitute this `(\w+)="(\d+)"` with `height:"100%"`

Comment: Thank you. The string is included a bigger html string. Would your code take any word in the string and change it to "height"?

Comment: if you want to change only width to height hardcode the width in regex like this `width="(\d+)"`.verify it [here](https://regex101.com/r/jB1zI1/3)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a php expert, but when it comes to regular expressions:

```
preg_replace("/(\d*)/", "100%", $input_lines);
```

Select all the digits within the group. Otherwise 3 distinct ones are created and thus replaced with your string.